# iOS7 screen capture has white noise

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I make ios7 apps.

And this app can capture. but it's white noise in addsubview images.
Please help me.


iOS6 and iOS5 is Not has white noise.
This is my code.

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
NSdate pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext ());
```

I use alpha png image in UIimage. And addSubview on view.

[white noise imase here](https://copy.com/X8CPCQZIHpTJ8QWk)

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 has a different way of making screen shots

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, self.window.screen.scale);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.frame afterScreenUpdates:NO];    
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `CGContextFillRect` to fill the rectangle with what? You don't seem to have defined the fill color or pattern. Although iOS7 has a new method as described in the previous answer, the previous methods should still work if coded properly.

My guess is that in previous OS, the fill color is defaulting to 0, or you have coded it properly there, and in iOS7, it must be using whatever happens to be in memory or something. Try calling `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` before `CGContextFillRect`.